# Group_by and filter or nest in tidyverse. How to unfilter() and then filter() again?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, tidyverse

In data analysis applied to psychology, we often want to check all results for each subject. Therefore, let's say I have this dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
ds <- data.frame(subject = rep(1:4, each=4),
                 metadata = c("congruent_1","congruent_2","incongruent_1", "incongruent_2"),
                 reaction_time = rnorm(16,mean = 0.1, sd=0.02))
```

I can get means and standard deviation grouped by each subject

```
#mean
ds %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  filter(metadata == "congruent_1" | metadata == "congruent_2") %>% 
  summarise(mean_cong = mean(reaction_time))
#sd
ds %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  filter(metadata =="incongruent_1" | metadata == "incongruent_2") %>% 
  summarise(sd_cong_incong = sd(reaction_time))
```

However, now I need to compute a variable with the result of `mean_cong` / `sd_cong_incong`. I'm sure this is possible via `group_by` or `nest` , but I'm not getting the right code to run that.

A fake code will be

```
ds %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  filter(metadata == "congruent_1" | metadata == "congruent_2") %>% 
  summarise(mean_cong = mean(reaction_time)) %>% 
  unfilter() %>% #<- I know this is not possible
  filter(metadata =="incongruent_1" | metadata == "incongruent_2") %>% 
  summarise(sd_cong_incong = sd(reaction_time)) %>% 
  mutate(pooled = mean_cong/sd_cong_incong)
```

And a fake output will be:

[image: fake output]
I want to remain within tidyverse environment.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean to put ``sd(reaction_time)`` to calculate the standard deviation rather than ``mean(reaction_time)``, or do I misyunderdstand your question?

Comment: yes. thank you. I changed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include logic within the summarise expression like this:

```
ds %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(subject) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(
        mean_cong = mean(reaction_time[metadata == "congruent_1" | metadata == "congruent_2"]),
        sd_cong = sd(reaction_time[metadata == "incongruent_1" | metadata == "incongruent_2"])
        ) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
        new_var = mean_cong/sd_cong
        )
```